# Looking for a sci-fi story title -- possibly YA or kids educational - "Canned Heat"

Tags: story-identification

As a kid (back in the Jurassic era before calculators, i.e. early 70's) I remember reading a sci-fi story.  This came back to me recently in a discussion about young Sci-Fi but I couldn't remember the title.  I seem to remember that I read it in some educational context, which I can't nail down.

Here are the elements that stuck in my brain:

- A human colony on a planet in an ice-age
- Aliens conquered and enslaved the humans.  The Aliens were (even drawn) as blue beach balls with tiny cherub wings and childlike human heads on top
- The Aliens controlled all sources of heat on the planet.  They used "cans" of heat as a method of rationing to control the humans
- Of course the story revolved around young people / kids rebelling against the aliens

Even as a kid, I thought this was the stupidest sci-fi story I had read in my young life.  I was probably biased because I had just finished Niven's Ringworld.